# ggplot2 - geom_path deleting paths when coloring by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

#### Update: found an answer but I can't say I understand it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47498831/2192578

#### Original issue:

I have 2 plots that are exactly the same, with only 1 exception: the coloring (pictures below). How can I make it such that the paths are still connecting? I believe this happens because geom_path() is basically building 3 different plots and overlapping them. How can I color different traces of the same path instead?

For reference, this is the code I'm using basically:

```
demand %>% ggplot(aes(x = prices, y = quantities, color = active_segments)) + 
  geom_path()
```

vs

```
demand %>% ggplot(aes(x = prices, y = quantities) + 
  geom_path()
```

[image: without coloring]
[image: with coloring]

Sample data frame:

```
structure(list(prices = c(210, 211.5, 213, 214.5, 216, 217.5, 
219, 220.5, 222, 223.5, 225, 226.5, 228, 229.5, 231, 232.5, 234, 
235.5, 237, 238.5, 240, 241.5, 243, 244.5, 246, 247.5, 249, 250.5, 
252, 253.5, 255, 256.5, 258, 259.5, 261, 262.5, 264, 265.5, 267, 
268.5, 270, 271.5, 273, 274.5, 276, 277.5, 279, 280.5, 282, 283.5, 
285, 286.5, 288, 289.5, 291, 292.5, 294, 295.5, 297, 298.5, 300, 
301.5, 303, 304.5, 306, 307.5, 309), quantities = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25), Segment1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Segment2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Segment3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), active_segments = c("All segments", 
    "All segments", "All segments", "All segments", "All segments", 
    "All segments", "All segments", "All segments", "All segments", 
    "All segments", "All segments", "All segments", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", 
    "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3 and 2", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", 
    "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", 
    "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", 
    "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", 
    "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", 
    "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", "Segment 3", 
    "Segment 3")), row.names = c(1L, 151L, 301L, 451L, 601L, 
751L, 901L, 1051L, 1201L, 1351L, 1501L, 1651L, 1801L, 1951L, 
2101L, 2251L, 2401L, 2551L, 2701L, 2851L, 3001L, 3151L, 3301L, 
3451L, 3601L, 3751L, 3901L, 4051L, 4201L, 4351L, 4501L, 4651L, 
4801L, 4951L, 5101L, 5251L, 5401L, 5551L, 5701L, 5851L, 6001L, 
6151L, 6301L, 6451L, 6601L, 6751L, 6901L, 7051L, 7201L, 7351L, 
7501L, 7651L, 7801L, 7951L, 8101L, 8251L, 8401L, 8551L, 8701L, 
8851L, 9001L, 9151L, 9301L, 9451L, 9601L, 9751L, 9901L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please [make the question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing the data in `demand` as plain text (_e.g._ using `dput()`).

Comment: The problem is that the "demand" data frame has over 12k rows haha, let me see if I can get some good markers. Didn't know about this dput thing, pretty cool!

Comment: Also a suggestion: for large datasets, you can "pick" out a representative sample of rows through use of the `sample()` function.  So for `demand`, you could sample 100 rows via: `dput(demand[sample(1:nrow(demand), 100),])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, because it highlights how the aesthetics `color=` (or `fill=`) and `group=` work in `ggplot`.  `ggplot` is written such that graphics are simple to create, and as such, it's doing a bit of guesswork and figuring out on its own based on your input.

Here's a sample dataset and simple path plot:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  y=c(10, 10, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2),
  grp=c('A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D')
)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw()
p + geom_path()
```

[image]

Note that the plot above is identically produced when you input this code:

```
p + geom_line()
```

When you think about it, `ggplot` is drawing all those lines by connecting all points together.  It is smart enough to know that the data supplied is all part of the same set and should have lines connecting all of it: `ggplot` would refer to this dataset as belonging to the same aesthetic `group`.  You can reproduce something similar to what you are seeing as follows:

```
# method 1:
p + geom_line(aes(color=grp))

# method 2:
p + geom_path(aes(color=grp))

# method 3:
p +
    geom_line(data=df[which(df$grp=='A'),], aes(color=grp)) +
    geom_line(data=df[which(df$grp=='B'),], aes(color=grp)) +
    geom_line(data=df[which(df$grp=='C'),], aes(color=grp)) +
    geom_line(data=df[which(df$grp=='D'),], aes(color=grp))
```

[image]

I showed all three methods above to prove a point: the same thing is going on in each one, and the most descriptive method above illustrating what's going on with the line-drawing is method 3.  Applying a `color=` aesthetic ***also*** has the effect of telling `ggplot` that you want to group the points according to `df$grp`, and *connect lines based on that grouping*.  If you remove the color and want to draw the same lines, just use the `group=` aesthetic alone:

```
p + geom_path(aes(group=grp))
```

[image]

#### Great... but how do we fix it?

Now that you understand that `color=` and `group=` work in a similar way, what happens when you use them *together* in the same call?  Looking at the above examples, we see two things are actually going on when we use `color=`:

1. The color of the lines is adjusted to match `df$grp`
2. The line connectivity is drawn according to `df$grp`

When you use both the `group=` and the `color=` aesthetic, the `group=` controls the connectivity of the lines and the `color=` aesthetic just controls the color.  This means if we break it down, we want to ***color*** the lines based on `df$grp`, but we want to ***connect*** the lines based on the "whole dataset".  Here, we have to specify `color=group`, but we can actually put nearly anything we want for the `group=` aesthetic... as long as it's all going to be the same no matter the observation:

```
# method 1 <-- this works
p + geom_path(aes(color=grp, group=1))

# method 2 <-- this works
p + geom_path(aes(color=grp, group='pasta'))

# method 3 <-- this returns an ERROR
p + geom_path(aes(color=grp, group=pasta))
```

[image]

Most people just use method 1 above (set `group=1`), but the point is that `ggplot` will apply "1" to every observation in the dataframe, and as long as 1 is 1 for all observations in your dataframe (hint: 1 is going to be 1), it will say they are all part of the same group.  Likewise, `"pasta"` is always `"pasta"` for every observation.  The third method does not work, because `ggplot` expects `pasta` (no quotes) is a variable/column in your dataframe.

Hope that illustrates why you are seeing that issue and also highlights the solution.  The same relationship holds true with `fill=`, `size=`, etc... and `group=`.  Your solution is to use `color=` to tell `ggplot` how to color the lines, but indicate that you want it to be "all part of the same group" when actually drawing the line and connecting points by supplying a `group=` aesthetic.