# How to plot a single line in different color and shape in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to have the following line `plotted` in a `red` and `dashed` type after `June 01` ?

```
library(tidyverse)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2001-09-30"), by = "days"),
                  V1 = runif(273, 1, 10))
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Date, y = V1))+
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot line plot different colors for sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498588/ggplot-line-plot-different-colors-for-sections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subset `DF`

```r
ggplot(DF[DF$Date < as.Date("2001-06-01"), ], aes(x = Date, y = V1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = DF[DF$Date >= as.Date("2001-06-01"), ], col = "red", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new variable based on whether dates are after June 1 or not.

```
DF$x <- DF$Date>as.Date('2001-06-01')

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Date, y = V1, col=x))+
  geom_line(aes(lty=x), show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","red"))
```

[image]

**Required libraries:**

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Comment: or just use the conditional statement in the aes call directly